# How to know which tables's checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a function

```
function collect_users_and_groups() {
   var tos = [];
   $('#mytable12 input:checked, #groupsTable1 input:checked').each(function(i, elt) {
       //alert("to groups");
       var dataids = $(this).parent().attr("data-selected").split(",");
       alert("dataids  "+dataids);
       var name = $.trim($(this).parent().next().text());
       tos.push(name);
   });

   return tos.join(', ');
}
```

which is called when I select check boxes
Actually `groupsTable1` has **data-selected attribute** but `mytable12`  does not have.
I want to call this `var dataids = $(this).parent().attr("data-selected").split(",");`

when checkbox of groupsTable1  is clicked
Please tell me how to do?

This is the full [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/LBPB6/49/),the above js codes can be found in between 22-33 in the js section

Comment: `$(this).closest('table').data("selected").split(",");` is it?

Comment: @Jai i didnt get you?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. So you want to call the above function when the checkbox is ticked? Is that what your having trouble with? Your happy with the obtaining of the data (which I think it what Jai is trying to fix).

Comment: @Liam see I have 2 tables one is having dataselected attribute and another does not have.I want the dataids if i select the checkbox of groupsTable1  table

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.is()` to check table is groupsTable1.

```
function collect_users_and_groups() {
   var tos = [];
   $('#mytable12 input:checked, #groupsTable1 input:checked').each(function(i, elt) {

        //Check table is groupsTable1
        if($(this).closest('table').is("#groupsTable1")){
            //alert("to groups");
            var dataids = $(this).parent().attr("data-selected").split(",");
            alert("dataids  "+dataids);
            var name = $.trim($(this).parent().next().text());
            tos.push(name);
        }
   });
   return tos.join(', ');
}
```

### OR

Simply use

```
 $('#mytable12 input:checked, #groupsTable1 input:checked').each(function(i, elt) {
```

instead of

```
 $('#groupsTable1 input:checked').each(function(i, elt) {
```

Comment: If i use your 2nd way then I have to change ` $("input:checkbox", "#mytable12, #groupsTable1").on('change', function () {
        var tos = collect_users_and_groups();
        $("#ToAdd").html(tos);
    });`

Comment: @JqueryLearner, What about first one

Comment: I was trying the 1st way but it is showing error in the fiddle.So looking into it

Comment: I did your way see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/LBPB6/50/) but the problem is it shows the `alert("dataids  "+dataids);` for both the table

Comment: any solutions you have?

Comment: @JqueryLearner, You have too much code there? Can you narrow it down. As I don't know exact workflow. i.e. How to trigger events

Comment: I have removed unnecessary codes http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/LBPB6/51/